# Determine if an object is dynamically allocated or not in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have a simple C++ class for which I need to know whether an object should be delete'd or not at a certain point in my program. The mechanism should be portable across platforms and modern C++ compilers.

One way of doing it I can think of is: have a member field which is not initialized by the constructor but instead is assigned by the overloaded operator new, like so:

```
class message
{
protected:
    int id;
    bool dynamic;
public:
    message(int _id): id(_id)
    {
        // don't touch `dynamic` in the constructor
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
        message* m = (message*)::operator new(size);
        m->dynamic = true;
        return m;
    }

    void operator delete(void* m)
    {
        if (((message*)m)->dynamic)
            ::operator delete(m);
    }
};
```

Apart form that it "feels" wrong, what is wrong with this method?

**Edit:** should have mentioned that the object is either dynamic or static (and never stack-local) and thus is guaranteed to be either zeroed or initialized with `new`.

Comment: *Why* do you need this? I can guarantee that this is the wrong way to go about it, even if there was a way to do what you ask (I'm fairly certain there is not). You shouldn't have to decide at run time whether to `delete` a pointer or not, because you should know (edit: at design time, i.e. a priori as far as the program is concerned) who owns what and what its lifetime is.

Comment: Make the destructor `private`. Then the answer is always "yes".

Comment: @delnan: no, you can't guarantee that :) It's a question of optimization. I have a message queue with a lot of messages passing by; in some cases they are dynamically allocated, but in some other cases, just for the sake of optimization, I can re-use static objects (and of course make sure a static object enters the message queue only once).

Comment: @mojuba: So your question should be "I have a message queue and want to optimize it like this, how do I...". See the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @GManNickG: no, my question is: I have objects that may be static or dynamic and I want these objects to be destroyed in just one place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static and dynamic memory allocation of objects in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814140/static-and-dynamic-memory-allocation-of-objects-in-c)

Comment: @Borgleader: the linked question is about the total number of objects allocated dynamically or statically in a program, whereas my question is about determining whether a given object is dynamic or static. Totally different questions, it seems.

Comment: @mojuba no its exactly the same principle. in order to count static vs dynamic you have to be able to determine between the two, and you'll see that the answers talk about that.

Comment: @Borgleader: ok, agreed, sorry about that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor needs to set `dynamic` to false, and then instead of overriding `new`, you need a static method like:

```
static message *createMessage(int _id)
{
    message *ret = new message(_id);
    ret->dynamic = true;
    return ret;
}
```

And then call that method instead of `new`ing a `message`.

Comment: But then it's always overwritten, isn't it?

Comment: Only when `new` is called. If it's a stack allocation, `dynamic` will remain set to `false`.

Comment: @JimBuck: No, the constructor runs *after* `operator new`, so even if `operator new` sets `dynamic` to `true`, the constructor will replace that with `false`.

Comment: It is true, I already edited my question: in my case objects are either dynamic or static, i.e. either created with `new` or have all fields zeroed.

Comment: Ahh, I edited without seeing your change. If so, then you are good. However, like all others have mentioned, this is a Really Bad Design(tm).

Comment: @Jim Buck: actually I like the idea of providing my own create() method like you described and, say, hiding the operator new() behind `private` (actually `protected`).

Answer (score 3):

Don’t do this. Apart from the fact that it won’t work, an object shouldn’t be managing anything about its own lifetime. You can use a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, and if the object is stack-allocated, you know at its allocation site; in that case, you can supply a no-op deleter such as the following:

```
struct null_deleter {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(const T*) const {}
};
```

Comment: You probably don't get the problem. Message objects in my case are processed and possibly also destroyed in one point of my program, while they can be created in many different places. I want to optimize my message queue by re-using static message objects whenever possible, i.e. when a message is guaranteed to enter the queue only once. It's a question of optimisation. So no, it's a run-time thing rather than compile-time.

Comment: @mojuba: If he doesn't get it, it's because you didn't say what it was in the question.